# Initializing structure pointer with array of structure

Tags: arrays, pointers, initialization, structure

I have a following doubt

I have a structure array. Before I had it initialized directly and was using in my code.
But I was suggested to use pointers instead of direct structure. But I cannot get the pointer pointing to the array of structre properly.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int a;
    int b;
} cqiReport;


cqiReport s_cqiReport[2][2];    
cqiReport *ptr[2], *ptr2, *ptr3;
s_cqiReport[0][0].a=1;
s_cqiReport[0][0].b=1;
*ptr= s_cqiReport;
    *ptr2= s_cqiReport[0][0];
    *ptr3= s_cqiReport[1][0];
```

I get ptr[0] pointing to s_cqiReport[0][0] properly but ptr[2] points to some junk.
How do i get ptr2[1] point to s_cqiReport[1][0]?

Please Help
Thanks
DSP guy

Comment: Are you working in C or C++?  It looks more like C than C++ but you should retag your question with the language designation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is kind of a mess. You've got s_cqiReport as a multidimensional array and ptr as a single-dimensioned array. The line

```
*ptr = s_cqiReport
```

doesn't make sense.

Also, you haven't initialized anything to an actual instance of cqiReport.

Try the following.

```
cqiReport *foo = new cqiReport;
foo->a = 9;
foo->b = 3;
```

This doesn't answer your question, but it should help.

Comment: HI Mj,actually I do not want to initialize using pointers. Initialization  is already done. I want the pointer to point to correct structure array address.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to realize is that an array actually is a pointer, so `*ptr` already points to `s_cqiReport[0][0]`, because it's equal to `s_cqiReport` which is itself a pointer.

Now if you want to get your pointer to point to a value, you have to use the `&` operator, which essentially means "address of", so something like `ptr3= &(s_cqiReport[1][0])` makes the pointer point where you want it to.

Likewise, I believe that `ptr3 = s_cliReport + 2` will also cause ptr3 to point where you seem to want it to point, but I would avoid performing arithmatic on your pointers until you have a strong understanding of pointers and how they work.